# How to do != for strings

Tags: java, string, compare

I'm making a program in java and its all going great until I wanted to make a while loop that is like this:

`while(String.notEqual(Something)){...}`

I know there is no such thins as notEqual but is there something similar?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the ! syntax. eg

```
if (!"ABC".equals("XYZ"))
{
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `.equals` in combination with the not `!` operator. from the [JLS §15.15.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.6),

> The type of the operand expression of the unary `!` operator must be
>   `boolean` or `Boolean`, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> The type of the unary logical complement expression is `boolean`.
>
> At run-time, the operand is subject to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) if
>   necessary. The value of the unary logical complement expression is
>   `true` if the (possibly converted) operand value is `false`, and `false` if
>   the (possibly converted) operand value is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

```
String a = "hello";
String b = "nothello";
while(!a.equals(b)){...}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String text1 = new String("foo");
String text2 = new String("foo");

while(text1.equals(text2)==false)//Comparing with logical no
{
   //Other stuff...
}

while(!text1.equals(text2))//Negate the original statement
{
   //Other stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want case-sensitive comparison use `equals()`, otherwise you can use `equalsIgnoreCase()`.

```
String s1 = "a";
String s2 = "A";

s1.equals(s2); // false

if(!s1.equals(s2)){
  // do something
}

s1.equalsIgnoreCase(s2); // true
```

Another way of string comparison that is useful for some cases (e.g. sorting) is to use `compareTo` which returns `0` if the strings are equal, `> 0` if s1 > s2 and `< 0` otherwise

```
if(s1.compareTo(s2) != 0){ // not equal

}
```

There is also `compareToIgnoreCase`

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!string.equals(Something))
{
   // Do some stuffs
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a thing called notEquals so if you want negation use !

```
while(!"something".equals(yourString){
//do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have change the string in your loop, it is better to take the NULL condition into consideration.

```
while(something != null && !"constString".equals(something)){
     //todo...
}
```